# Как передать данные из клиентского node js приложения на сервер node.js?

Tags: node.js

на клиентских ПЭВМ в фоне работает мини приложение на node.js, которое должно отправлять инфо о системе на сервака (на котором равернут web сервер-node.js). Подскажите как происходит обмен данными 2х node.js приложений

PS: на клиенте и серваке стоит винда

Comment: Откройте на сервере socket, а на клиенте цепляйтесь туда и пуште данные. Или если у вас поднят Express на сервере, ну сделайте там адрес какой-то и отправляйте Post/Get запрос туда.

Answer (score 0):

Првиет!

Гугли про socket.io. на главном приложении будет развернут сервер, а на остальных клиенты (библиотека socket.io-client). Это обеспечит обмен данными в реальном времени. В интернете полно примеров кода, так что не заблудишься)